# SQLite doesn't remove last object from db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, contextmenu

I am doing an app that lets you write activities to do.
On the main activity, there's a ListView, which shows the activities according to the date especified in a DatePicker inside a DialogFragment.
I'm using SQLite to save the activities, and so far there's no problem saving them.
If you long press an item of the ListView, a context menu appears with a single option "Delete Activity", calling the method removeActivity, which deletes the activity from the static ArrayList System.activities, that stores every activity created, AND should delete the activity from the database, using the activity's attribute cod, which is unique for every instance of an activity.

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
    int mDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int mMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH); // August, month
                                                                // starts from 0
    int mYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
    ArrayList<String> listNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<ActivityToDo> acts = System.activities;
    boolean listHasItems = false;
    int position;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Remove title bar
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    removeActivitesBeforeCurrentDate();
    ToDoSQLiteHelper actdb = new ToDoSQLiteHelper(this, "db", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = actdb.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Activities", null);
    System.activities.clear();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ActivityToDo act = new ActivityToDo(c.getString(1),
                    c.getString(2), c.getString(3));
            act.setDate(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(4)),
                    Integer.parseInt(c.getString(5)),
                    Integer.parseInt(c.getString(6)));
            System.activities.add(act);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Button btnNewAct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewAct);
    final TextView txtV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPickDate);
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listNames.add("Pick date to search activity.");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listNames);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    registerForContextMenu(listview);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            if (listHasItems) {
                ActivityToDo a = acts.get(position);
                String[] datosAct = new String[6];
                datosAct[0] = a.getName();
                datosAct[1] = a.getDescr();
                datosAct[2] = a.getPriority();
                datosAct[3] = Integer.toString(a.getDay());
                datosAct[4] = Integer.toString(a.getMonth());
                datosAct[5] = Integer.toString(a.getYear());
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ShowActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("datos", datosAct);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        // This handles the message send from DatePickerDialogFragment on
        // setting date
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message m) {
            Bundle b = m.getData();
            mDay = b.getInt("set_day");
            mMonth = b.getInt("set_month");
            mYear = b.getInt("set_year");
            String date = "";
            if (mDay < 10) {
                date += "0" + mDay + "/";
            } else {
                date += mDay + "/";
            }
            int mes = mMonth + 1;
            if (mes < 10) {
                date += "0" + mes + "/";
            } else {
                date += mes + "/";
            }
            date += mYear;
            txtV.setText(date);
            buildList(mDay, mMonth + 1, mYear);
        }
    };

    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("set_day", mDay);
            b.putInt("set_month", mMonth);
            b.putInt("set_year", mYear);
            DatePickerDialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerDialogFragment(
                    mHandler);
            datePicker.setArguments(b);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(datePicker, "date_picker");
            // Opening the DatePicker fragment
            ft.commit();
        }
    };
    txtV.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btnNewAct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

protected void buildList(int d, int m, int y) {
    acts = System.searchByDate(d, m, y);
    listNames.clear();
    if (acts != null && acts.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < acts.size(); i++) {
            listNames.add(acts.get(i).getName());
        }
        listHasItems = true;
    } else {
        listHasItems = false;
        listNames.add("No activities for that date.");
    }
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listNames);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public void mostrarToast(String txt) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txt,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

private void removeActivitesBeforeCurrentDate() {
    ToDoSQLiteHelper actdb = new ToDoSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(),
            "db", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = actdb.getWritableDatabase();
    ActivityToDo aux;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Activities", null);
    if (System.activities.size() != 0 && c.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < System.activities.size(); i++) {
            aux = System.activities.get(i);
            if (aux.getYear() < Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
                    && aux.getMonth() - 1 < Calendar.getInstance().get(
                            Calendar.MONTH)
                    && aux.getDay() < Calendar.getInstance().get(
                            Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                System.activities.remove(i);
                int cod = aux.getCod();
                db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Activities WHERE cod=" + cod);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (listHasItems) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        position = info.position;
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menulistitem, menu);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    removeActivity(position);
    buildList(mDay, mMonth + 1, mYear);
    return true;
}

private void removeActivity(int pos) {
    ToDoSQLiteHelper actdb = new ToDoSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(),
            "db", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = actdb.getWritableDatabase();
    ActivityToDo aux;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Activities", null);
    if (System.activities.size() != 0 && c.moveToFirst()) {
        aux = System.activities.get(pos);
        System.activities.remove(pos);
        int cod = aux.getCod();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Activities WHERE cod=" + cod);
    }
    c.close();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.finish();
}
```

}

But the `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM Activities WHERE cod=" + cod);` doesn't seem to work for the last activity that remains in the database. Example: I pick a date, there's two activities for the day, I delete both of them, the ListView shows the text "No activity for that date", which is what should happen, but when I start the app again, the activity that was supposingly deleted at last, appears there. Same if there's only one activity for that date, that's why I say that it doesn't seem to delete an activity if it's the last thing in the database.
Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

My SQLite class:

```
public class ToDoSQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// crear tabla de usuario
// agregar DATE
String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE Activities (cod INTEGER, name TEXT, descr TEXT, priority TEXT, day TEXT, month TEXT, year TEXT)";
public ToDoSQLiteHelper(Context contexto, String nombre,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(contexto, nombre, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnterior,
        int versionNueva) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Activities");
    db.execSQL(sqlCreate);
}
```

}